# Where is the call of the button_click method in C# in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, winforms

(Newby on Visual Studio 2019 and C#, familiar with OOP in Java)

Visual Studio 2019 icw .NET windows dev. Coding in C#.

When I add an button to a form and doubleclik on it, the method-definition gets created in Form1.cs and looks like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

But where does this method get called? I've looked in the button class, control class and form1 class but can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is more like "when" is the code called... It is an event that the `button1` subscribes to… look in the `Form1.Designer.cs` file and expand the code and you should see something like… `this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);` … this subscribes to the `button1`’s “Click” event… it will run the `button1_Click` code when `button1` is clicked. I am guessing this is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you for your quick and clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

The method (`button1_Click`) is wrapped into an `EventHandler` and added as subscriber of the `Click` event of the form object container.

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

The above code is generated by the designer in a different file groupped by VS together with our source file.

In fact your form is a C# partial class.
The rest of the class is defined in the file `.Designer.cs` (for instance `Form1.Designer.cs`).

So your method will be called as soon as button will be clicked.

Answer (score 2):

> But where does this method get called?

The WinForms framework calls it, because it's assigned as a handler to an Event.

This is hooked up in the form's Designer file, which is auto-generated by Visual Studio. It's named `{FormName}.Designer.cs`.

[image]

Inside that file is a Region called "Windows Form Designer generated code", which when you made modifications to the form with the visual designer will update accordingly. *This* is actually where your method is being registered as an event handler.

For example, in my simple calculator app, the "8" button is being assigned to a method named `ButtonClick` when clicked.

```
// 
// btn8
// 
this.btn8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 46);
this.btn8.Name = "btn8";
this.btn8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 36);
this.btn8.TabIndex = 2;
this.btn8.Text = "8";
this.btn8.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.btn8.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonClick);
```

You can also view and modify the assigned events from the Events tab in the Properties paine in the Form Designer, when the correct control is selected.

[image]